# AWS Elastic Beanstalk SPF Record & Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ses

Basically what we've got is an application running on the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) platform. Given this, the application itself is on multiple servers and to ensure mail delivery from the system, we need to add a sufficient SPF record for the Amazon servers to ensure they're approved to send email for the domain.

I suppose my question is two part then. Firstly, do all AWS Elastic Beanstalk setups use the [Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) by default and then in that case we can just use `include:amazonses.com` in the SPF record? If not the case, how can we ensure mails sent by the site from the Amazon servers are approved - can we just use an `include:domain.com` sort of record, or do we need to add some sort of include for an Amazon URL that encompasses the elastic setup?

Answer (score 4):

Applications running on [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) are **not** using [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) automatically, rather simply use the SMTP facility available for the underlying regular [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances, and SMTP on Amazon EC is indeed throttled and has less reputation with other providers, see e.g. [Email Changes](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=149592#149592).

[Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) is an application level *outbound-only email-sending service* , which you'll need to integrate yourself by one of two means:

- using the API for [Sending an Email Through Amazon SES Using an AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-send-using-sdk.html)
- using *an SMTP-compatible programming language, application, or software package* for [Sending an Email Through Amazon SES Using SMTP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-send-using-smtp.html)

The latter implies that you can configure your OS to also use Amazon SES as the outbound SMTP destination in an EC2 instance directly, however, while [Customizing and Configuring AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) is possible, even down to [Using Custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html), usually it is much easier to target the SES SMTP endpoint from within your application instead.

- In case you want to go down that route, [Authenticating Email with SPF in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html) has the resp. details, and [Authenticating Email with DKIM in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dkim.html) is also available.

However, if you *really* do not want to dive into SES and rather just use what's available via EC2, [Sending Email from EC2 Instances](http://www.practicalclouds.com/content/guide/sending-email-ec2-instances) provides a detailed *list of actions you should take in order to host/send you email from EC2*, including *4. Set up SPF (Sender Policy Framework) DNS Records*:

> [...] Create the following SPF record (which is a DNS TXT entry) to
>   state that only hosts with an MX record for your domain (i.e. hosts
>   which receive mail for your domain) are allowed to send email on
>   behalf of it: -
>
> ```
> @ IN TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"
> ```
>
> You can also optionally allow other specific hosts, such as Googlemail
>   may also send email on behalf of your domain:
>
> ```
> @ IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a:mail.google.com -all"
> ```